# How do I activate a Laravel package via dowloaded files (not via Composer)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel package I would like to use in my project. I have tested it already and I know I'd need to customize quite a lot of it to fit my needs.

Overriding files in the `vendor` directory is always quite a chore, especially if you need to touch PHP, Vue, CSS files, etc. Hence, I don't want to go via the usual Composer installation. I also don't care much about future updates to the package, as it already has a solid base.

So the question is: **After I download the package files from GitHub and after I place them in their respective directories in my Laravel app - is there a specific list of steps to take in order to make sure the inserted package works?** Or is it more like, do it and fix issues one by one until it works?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Composer allows you to choose the local package instead of the remote one.

1. Create a `packages` folder in the base directory (the `packages` folder and Laravel's `composer.json` file must be in the same directory).
2. Put your downloaded package into `packages` (packages/packageName).
3. Replace the following line in your Laravel's `composer.json`.

   ```json
   "require": {
   ```

   by

   ```json
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type" : "path",
           "url" : "./packages/*",
           "options" : {
               "symLink" : true
           }
       }
   ],
   "require": {
   ```
4. Run `composer require authorName/packageName` command in the console.